# Not able to apply footer css to a footer dialog in Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have around 20 modal dialogs(all have same style) in my app-body and one modal dialog in app-footer and both of these have different styles.I am able to load dialogs.

```
<div class="app d-flex flex-column">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-body class="flex-grow-1"></app-body>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

The modal dialog of footer is outside of app-body ,so i  use below code to load its scss

```
::ng-deep .modal-dialog {
  width: 70%;
}
```

Modal dialogs html look like this when loaded in html

App-body dialog:

```
<modal-container class="modal fade show" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;" aria-modal="true">
```

..

Footer dialog:

```
<modal-container class="modal fade show" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;" aria-modal="true">
```

..

But the problem is , this footer modal dialog is now applied to all other modal dialogs in my app-body components.

To fix this i applied the below css

```
:host ::ng-deep .modal-dialog {
  width: 70%;
}
```

This time the modal dialogs style of my app-body components is applied on my footer.

So how do i make sure my footer gets its own css without getting impacted or not impacting other modal dialogs in app-body.

Comment: Add a class to either the parent element or the `app-footer` tag, and use the class in your selector

Comment: yes, just give the footer its own class and target that.